# Maximum Likelihood Estimation and Moment Estimator

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

> A gas station needs at least $\alpha$ minutes to change the oil of
> your car. The actually needed time $X$ varies in $X\geq \alpha$ and
> varies from customer to customer. We can assume, that this time is
> described by a exponentially distributed random variable. The random
> variable $X$ has the following probability density function
>
> $$f_X(x):=\begin{cases}e^{\alpha - x} & x\geq \alpha\\0 &
> > \text{else}\end{cases} \tag{1}$$
>
> i.e. $X=\alpha + Z$ whereas $Z \sim Exp(1)$.
>
> To estimate $\alpha$, we measured the time in minutes needed to change
> the oil of 10 random customers:
>
> $$4.2 \quad 3.1 \quad 3.6 \quad 4.5 \quad 5.1 \quad 7.6 \quad 4.4
> > \quad 3.5 \quad 3.8 \quad 4.3$$
>
> from which we get the empirical mean of $\bar{x}_{10}=4.41$. I know
> want to compute:
>
> 1. The Maximum-Likelihood-Estimator (Note: We can't differentiate it, so we need to get the maximum in a different way.)
> 2. Method of moment estimator (I hope I translated that correctly)
>
> for $\alpha$ and I want to evaluate it for the give sample.

So what they do now is:

1.) The Likelihood function is given by

\begin{align}
L(\alpha;x_1,\dots,x_n) &=\prod_{i=1}^n f_\alpha (x_i)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^ne^{\alpha-x_i}1_{[\alpha,\infty)}(x_i)\\
&=\exp(n\alpha - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n1_{[\alpha,\infty)}(x_i)\\
&=\exp(n\alpha - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)\cdot 1_{[\alpha,\infty)}(\min_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i)\\
&=\begin{cases} \exp(n\alpha - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i) & \alpha \leq \min_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}
\tag{2}
\end{align}

whereas

$$1_A(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\in A \\ 0 &\text{else}\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

To maximize the above Likelihood-Function, $\alpha$ should be as big as possible but it can't be bigger than $\min_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i$. So the Maximum-Likelihood-Estimator for $\alpha$ is

$\hat{\alpha}=\min_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i \quad \text{resp. as a random variable} \quad \hat{\alpha}=\min_{1\leq i\leq n} X_i \tag{4}$

2.)

It is $\mu=E(X)=\alpha + E(Z) = \alpha + 1$ so $\alpha = \mu -1$ and the "moment-estimator" is given by

$$\hat{\alpha}=\hat{\mu}-1=\bar{X}_n-1 \tag{5}$$

So we get for the given values $\hat{\alpha}=\bar{x}_{10}-1=4.31$

**Question:**

1. Why do we need $I_{[\alpha,\infty)}$? Isn't the "else"-case impossible because it has probability 0?

Comment: The pdf of $X_i$ is still defined when $x_i<\alpha$.